# Why does this event listener pick up an event sent before it was added

Tags: javascript, vue.js

I have this vue JS code. Clicking on the account `<a>` tag causes the `toggle` method to run. The toggle method adds an event listener to the document but as soon as toggle is run the event listener fires and runs `close` even though the event listener was added as a result of the event so the event must have already happened. Why does this event run and how can I get it to not run as soon as toggle is run. It should only run on any click after the first click on the `<a>` tag.

```
<template>
    <div>
        <a v-on:click="this.toggle">Account</a>
        <nav v-if="this.open">
            <a>Profile</a>
            <a>Settings</a>
            <a>Sign Out</a>
            <a>Admin</a>
        </nav>
    </div>
</template>

<script lang='ts'>
    import { Vue } from 'vue-property-decorator'

    export default Vue.extend({
        data: function () {
            return {
                open: false
            }
        },
        methods: {
            toggle: function () {
                this.open = !this.open
                if (this.open) {
                    // Add click listener to whole page to close dropdown
                    document.addEventListener('click', this.close)
                }
            },
            close: function () {
                console.log('test')
                this.open = false;
                document.removeEventListener('click', this.close)
            }
        }
    })
</script>
```

Comment: After the toggle function has finished, the click event bubbles up and reaches the document. Since the listener is already added and active, it fires. Use `toggle: function (e) {` and in your function, call `e.stopPropagation();`

Comment: @ChrisG That works. Could you post it as an answer

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As Chris G noted in a comment, this is the event bubbling up to the document after you've added the listener. Fortunately, Vue makes this easy. You can change your event to `v-on:click.stop="this.toggle"`